# Execute an AJAX call on unload function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have to execute a code when the user try to leave is just a simple call to the server informing that have to delete a file, it doesn't make any response but the system don't call.

```
                    $(window).unload(function(){
                           alert(1)
                           window.key = document.getElememtsByTagName('body')[0].getAttribute('key');
                           catcher('clearBt');//The catcher makes the AJAX call like i show below.
                    });
//This is the call to the server.
        phone.open(method, address, true);
        phone.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        phone.send(reqStr);
```

I've try with onbeforeunload to but the result was the same...

Comment: Are you getting a JavaScript error? You'll need a semicolon after alert(1).

Comment: I don't have anything thats the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Great, i had the same problem with the Magento Checkout. I solved this way

```
var responseCancel= jQuery.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'checkout/onepage/callWsCancelOrder'; ?>',
        cache: false,
                  async: false
         }).responseText;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous by default and will end with the document unload. Try running it as a synchronous call instead.

You have to change this to

```
phone.open(method, address, false /*synchronous*/);
```

and the page should wait for the request to finish.

Comment: But the page doesn't will wait to the response?

Comment: It should do that. Synchronous means that the script will wait untill the request is finished. And as long as you don't return the, document should still be active.